# edittext not showing the typed text in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am using a simple login page.
The issue is that when testing in android htc wildfire,the user could not see the text typed till he press back or done

I would like the user to view his text while typing itself.
'
Could anyone please let me know how to resolve this?

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your problem is this:

`When user clicks in the EditText to type, the keyboard pops up and hides the EditText, thus the user can't see what he's typing`

For this, you can put that `EditText` into a `ScrollView` so that when keyboard pops-up, Android scrolls the `EditText` up. This way,the user can see what he's typing.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know whether it will help you or not. but am sharing because some other may be benifited. I got the same issue in my Kindle tablet.

And I have solved this just by adding the simple attribute to the edittext.

```
<EditText
     .........
     android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/Black"
/>
```

And its done. Now it will show each character you types.

If it helps you, I will suggest you to write the above attribute everytime you declare an edittext, even though this issue doesn't occur.